# Create new vector based on old vector

Tags: r, vector

I dont have that much of coding experience, especially when it comes to doing loops and after searching the web with similiar questions, I finally decided to open a new one up. I hope SO can help me.

Suppose I have a vector **b**

```
3
6
11
```

Now I want to create a new vector **c** looking like this:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
```

Rules are according to vector b: after 3 columns, I  number 1, after 6 columns I get number 2 , after 11 columns I get number 3 and so on...

**Important:** Length of new vector c should be the same as my data frame **df**

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec<-c(3,6,11)
> rep(1:length(vec),times=vec)
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

**UPDATE**

```
 fun=function( vec,len=14){
   rep(1:(length(vec)+1),times= c(diff(c(0,vec)),len-sum(diff(c(0,vec)))))
 }

> fun(c(3,6,11),14)
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

Comment: slighty nicer IMO: `rep(seq_along(vec), vec)`

Comment: @AndreElrico agree

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution, but not quite what I wanted...the number 2 should stop at the position 6

Comment: @pineapple like that?

Comment: @jyjek Yes, that's it! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
b <- c(3,6,11)
```

Suppose your dataframe is of length 14: `df <- data.frame(a= rep(NA, 14))`

```
df$c <- rep(1:(length(b)+1), times = c(3,diff(b), dim(df)[1] - sum(c(3, diff(b)))))

df
    a c
1  NA 1
2  NA 1
3  NA 1
4  NA 2
5  NA 2
6  NA 2
7  NA 3
8  NA 3
9  NA 3
10 NA 3
11 NA 3
12 NA 4
13 NA 4
14 NA 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This works for the mentioned vector b, but when giving a different vector likle c(7,14) it doesnt work anymore...